# Fetch Data of Different Organization?

Tags: apex, rest, httprequest, http, httpresponse

I have 2 Orgs- **Org A** & **Org B** both are ap1 Instance

In **Org A** I've created  a Connected app

In **Org B** I am  trying to Query accounts of **Org A** From the Connected App Through Http Call,  but I am getting the Data of **Org B** Itself

Is it Because of same Instance of Endpoint Url

Below is My Http Class After Getting the Access Token

```
 http h = new Http();
 HttpRequest eq1= new HttpRequest();
 eq1.setMethod('GET');
 eq1.setEndpoint('https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v33.0/query?q=SELECT+id,name,type,description,industry+FROM+account+ORDER+BY+name');

eq1.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
//eq1.setHeader('Authorization', acc);
eq1.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+acc);
Httpresponse hh1 = new HttpResponse();
hh1 = h.send(eq1);
```

Comment: where you are setting up your acc variable value. i.e. access token

Comment: are you sure when you got your accesstoken that you got it from Org A and not Org B (that is, you didn't self-authorize)?

Comment: @cropredy I am using connected app of Org A itself .. But.. How to check access token against the org